# VHDL Filter not getting output for first values

Tags: vhdl

I tried implementing a fir filter in VHDL but during the first three clocks I get no output and the error `at 0 ps, Instance /filter_tb/uut/ : Warning: There is an 'U'|'X'|'W'|'Z'|'-' in an arithmetic operand, the result will be 'X'(es).`.

Source file (I also have 2 other files for D Flip-Flops):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity filter is
    port ( x: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
            clk: in STD_LOGIC;
            y: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0));
end filter;


architecture struct of filter is


    type array1 is array (0 to 3) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal coef : array1 :=( "0001", "0011", "0010", "0001");

    signal c0, c1, c2, c3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0):="00000000";    
    signal s0, s1, s2, s3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) :="0000";
    signal sum: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0):="0000000000";


    component DFF is
        Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
                clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
                q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
    end component;

    component lDFF is
        Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
                clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
                q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0));
    end component;

begin       

        s0<=x;
        c0<=x*coef(0);  
        DFF1: DFF port map(s0,clk,s1);
        c1<=s1*coef(1);     
        DFF2: DFF port map(s1,clk,s2);
        c2<=s2*coef(2);     
        DFF3: DFF port map(s2,clk,s3);
        c3<=s3*coef(3);
        sum<=("00" & c0+c1+c2+c3);
        lDFF1: lDFF port map(sum,clk,y);

end struct;
```

Testbench:

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY filter_tb IS
END filter_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF filter_tb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT filter
    PORT(
         x : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         y : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal x : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal y : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;


BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: filter PORT MAP (
          x => x,
          clk => clk,
          y => y
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc1: process
   begin        

      x<="0001";
        wait for 10ns;
        x<="0011";
        wait for 10ns;
        x<="0010";
        wait for 10ns;
        --x<="0011";


   end process;

END;
```

Output:
[image: Output]

If anyonce could help, I'd appreciate it. I think it has something to do with the inital values of the signals c_i and s_i but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have build a series of three register making up a cascade of registers.
You have not provided a reset so the register contents will be Unknown. You use the registers for calculations without any condition. Thus you arithmetic calculations will see the Unknown values and fail as you have seen.

The first (simplest) solution would be to add a reset. But that is not the best solution. You will no longer get warnings but the first three cycles of your output will be based on the register reset value not of your input signal.
If you have a big stream and don't care about some incorrect values in the first clock cycle you can live with that.

The really correct way would be to have a 'valid' signal transported along side your data. You only present the output data when there is a 'valid'. This is the standard method to process data through any pipeline hardware structure.

By the way: you normally do **not** build D-ffs yourself. The synthesizer will do that for you. You just use a clocked process and process the data vectors in it.

---

> I have some questions. If I add a reset pin, when will I toggle it from 1 to 0? How can I create this circuit without explicitly using D-ffs?

You make a reset signal in the same way as you make your clock.

As to D-registers: they come out if you use the standard register VHDL code:

```
reg : process (clk,reset_n)
begin
   // a-synchronous active low reset
   if (reset_n='0') then 
      s0 <= "0000";
      s1 <= "0000";
      s2 <= "0000";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
      s0 <= x;
      s1 <= s0;
      s2 <= s1;
 ....
```

(Code entered as-is, not checked for syntax or typing errors)

Comment: I have some questions. If I add a reset pin, when will I toggle it from 1 to 0? How can I create this circuit without explicitly using D-ffs?

Answer (score 1):

Your FIR filter contains flip-flops. These flip-flops have no reset input and so power up in an unknown state. You simulator models this by initialising the flip-flops' outputs to `"UUUU"` (as the are four bits wide). A `'U'` `std_logic` value represents and uninitialised value.

So, your code behaves as you ought to expect. If you're not happy with that behaviour, you need to add a reset input and connect it to your flip-flops.

Comment: When should I turn the reset pin from 1 to 0?

Comment: VHDL is a hardware description language. You're designing digital hardware here. I think you need to learn some basic digital electronics, specifically about flip-flops and synchronous/asynchronous resets.